# Finding the camera position in a computer graphics exercise?

Tags: graphics, camera, position

Suppose we have an object as we see in the diagram below right, with base of 2x3 units and height of 2 units. If we assume that we use perspective projection, what should be the parameters of the camera to get the picture below?

[Link to the images here](http://i1310.photobucket.com/albums/s655/androsland/Untitled_zpsd834433a.png)